# How to use Bluebird.js with vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, bluebird

I'm trying to search for an example of how to use Bluebird.js with vue.js but haven't find anything.

I'm trying this in my main.js:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Promise from 'bluebird';       //<=== HERE
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(Promise);                      //<=== HERE

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
});
```

Comment: U can't just do `Vue.use` if it's not a Vue plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything.

As soon as you import Bluebird into the file, you can use it inside of the Vue instance.

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Promise from 'bluebird';       //<=== HERE
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  created: function() {
    // access Promise inside of vue instance e.g. var p1 = new Promise...
  }
});
```